# Xamarin best habits on switching between pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I'm new with `Xamarin.Forms`, and I'd like to know how to switch to a "previously loaded" Page.

Let say my App run, and it loads (as First Page) my `MainPage`. There I tweak some button/toggle (changing status), and than I click on a button that will load another Page (using `Navigation` model):

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNewPage());
```

Now here I want to return to the previous `MainPage`

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

But at this point, all content/button status are vanished (basically it creates a new `MainPage`).

Since its a LIFO, I aspect to have it on memory/stack. How can I recall the previous loaded `MainPage`? Or is it dangerous since GC could clean it at any point?

Notice that in this specific case this would works (since I just back one time):

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

But I'd like to use a selective approch (calling what I need where I am, learning the whole concept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that the `Navigation` object you use to Push and Pop has a `NavigationStack` property you can use to get previously pushed pages - assuming you didn't pop them.

To the best of my knowledge, there aren't any methods to directly navigate to an existing `Page` in the stack so you may have to get somewhat creative in your approach.

If `MainPage` is always at the bottom of your `NavigationStack`, you can use

```
await Navigation.PopToRootAsync()
```

to go back to the `Page` at the bottom of the stack.

If 'MainPage' can be elsewhere in the stack, you may have to maintain your own list of `Page`s separate from the `NavigationStack`.

Something like the following may work if you don't care about keeping the `Page`s between `MainPage` and your current page:

Note that you will want to create a separate `List` of `Page`s to remove as calling `RemovePage()` on the `NavigationStack` in the `foreach` loop will cause an exception sometimes, something to the effect of "Enumeration can't complete, collection has changed":

```
List<Page> pagesToRemove = new List<Page>();
foreach( Page page in Navigation.NavigationStack )
{
    if( page.GetType() != typeof(MainPage) && page != Navigation.NavigationStack.Last() )
    {
        pagesToRemove.Add(page);
    }
} 
// pagesToRemove now contains all Pages between your current page and MainPage

foreach( Page pageToRemove in pagesToRemove )
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(pageToRemove);
}
// the NavigationStack only contains MainPage (now the root) and your current page

// Pop to MainPage
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Someday it would be nice to have a `NavigateTo(Page)` or the like but for now this approach seems to work.